# Bootstrap multivariate time series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, multivariate-analysis, bootstrap

Given a variable `y` in time (in my case financial returns), I define a series of class labels encoding the sign of `y`: `target=0` if `sign(y)<=0`, else `target=1`.
I then try to predict the class at each time using a set of features `X`.

I am looking into ways to augment my dataset ([data augmentation](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/76013/how-to-do-data-augmentation-for-machine-learning-on-statistical-data) and [testing for overfitting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/563390/is-it-valid-to-do-roc-analysis-without-using-test-data) being two possible use cases).

A sensible approach for bootstrapping my data is to use [block bootstrap](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4431/resources-to-learn-about-block-bootstrap-in-time-series-analysis) with a careful definition of "block".
However, in my case that does not yield a high variability of the bootstrapped series (maybe I was overcautious in drawing y from same days within a month window).

[As an alternative](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13675/alternative-to-block-bootstrap-for-multivariate-time-series/13877#13877), I am looking into [MEboost](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v029i05) as it natively "accounts" for seasonality. However, I cannot quite see how to make it work with a multivariate time series.
As I understand, the algorithm samples from the empirical distribution of the data in a continuous manner. This means that the set of bootstrapped data might contain values not
contained in the original set of values.

**If** it is so, how can I go about bootstrapping in my case? Say that I ME bootstrap y, I then do not see how to modify the features in order to preserve the (unknown) relationship
between them. Also ME bootstrapping the each feature separately makes no sense to me.
Is it possible to apply MEboot to my problem?

Side questions:

- Is MEboot still used? (Some critiques [here](http://www.monticini.eu/wp/rdavidson.pdf))
- In general, could training on bootstrapped series improve a models' prediction?

Comment: If you are looking for a way to augment the data, bootstrap won't really work, because it doesn't create any "new" data, doesn't it?

Comment: I see the point. So it would probably not work to improve model's results. 
But I could still use the bootstrapped data to train a model on each and get some prediction error estimate, right?
It is a bit the concept at the base of my other use case: testing for overfitting (I re-train the model every day using all data and I basically do not have a test set).

Comment: But it wouldn't tell you about out-of-data performance. It sounds as [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Maybe instead tell us more about the underlying problem instead of getting an answer on possibly inadequate solution?

Comment: It probably is. I never extensively worked with multivariate time series and I am trying to figure out all the tricks I can use.
I will edit the question with more details on the problem and a more precise question.